# Is there any way I can display pdfs uploaded in my files using nodejs and ejs?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, multer

I created a way to upload files using Multer in my files then display their information to my frontend. My challenge is opening the uploaded PDF as when I click the link to open it says that it cannot get.

[image]

Comment: check this out https://github.com/ashwanibakshi/fileuplloaddownload

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your static files in Express.

Use `app.use(express.static('public'))` to specify that your static files are located on public folder.

And for get a file you don't need to add public in the url, for example:
http://localhost:3000/pdf/mypdf.pdf

See this [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: thank you so much kkkk imagine the public that i had added was causing this error

Comment: Perfect, you can mark this as resolved.